# Why let me begin to edit a comment if... "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" and 5 minutes has already elapsed?

Tags: feature-request, edits, comments

Stack Overflow prevents comments from being edited after the 5 minute mark. However, the edit button is not removed until the page is refreshed. In other words, if I post a comment and wait 6 minutes, I still have the option to edit that comment. And if I do edit that comment, it is only after I submit my changes that SO presents the error, "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes."

[image]

[image]

Why allow users to edit after this 5 minutes is up? Having an edit button that is clickable implies that when I submit my edit, everything will go through. Having an edit button present after 5 minutes and that only throws an error after I submit my edit seems like very poor feedback.

The age of the comment is updated constantly without requiring a refresh. So why can't the edit button be updated as well? Hide it? Even showing me the message as soon as I click edit would be better.

Comment: Just wanted to bring it to attention.

Comment: This could be a `feature-request`, you're right that if does look like a strange way to handle edits.

Comment: See the following posts on Meta SE: [Comments have a pointless “edit” button, even after the 5 min timeout has expired](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133924/comments-have-a-pointless-edit-button-even-after-the-5-min-timeout-has-expire) (existing feature request) and [Automatically remove the edit link for comments once they are no longer editable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62403/automatically-remove-the-edit-link-for-comments-once-they-are-no-longer-editable).

Comment: Not nearly as frustrating as spending 5-10 minutes on an answer, only to find it's been closed while you were typing.

Comment: Because the comment timestamps are static, and the error is thrown after querying the server.

Comment: I was going to report this bug a *long* time ago but I figured it would be status-declined because they would say who cares. Best of luck I guess.

Comment: @Charlie the visibility of the edit link could be updated at the same time as the displayed duration.  The timestamp is static, but the way it's displayed is not.

Comment: @HotLicks Don't answer crappy questions then.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense from a user interface point of view. If the edit button disappeared after 5 minutes, everybody not knowing about the 5 minutes timeout would be searching for it.

Comment: show edit button in "disabled" state (overstrike or grayed out) after 5 minutes with a hover tooltip over it saying "disabled 5 minutes after initial post"

Comment: @HotLicks If you are answering questions that will be closed, you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: @bjb568 - SO doesn't tell you the question will be closed.  You get no warning while editing your response, just a nasty message when you hit "Post your answer".

Comment: @HotLicks You have 3k rep, so you can see pending closevotes. But in any case, *you shouldn't even think about answering questions that **can** be closed*. If you see a question that might be a duplicate, is too broad, unclear, primarily opinion based, off-topic, or low quality - **don't answer it**.

Comment: @bjb568 - A question can go from open to closed in 5 minutes easy.  And pretty much any question can be closed -- it only takes a few people taking offense to it -- doesn't require a valid reason.  (Apparently it's not uncommon for folks to go to a chat room and get their buddies to kill some question they dislike, for whatever reason.)

Comment: @HotLicks If you use a browser that supports websockets, then yes, you do get a warning within 30 seconds of a question being closed.

Comment: @HotLicks If you get in that situation, and you feel that the question and answer are useful, there is something that you can do.  If the question was closed as a duplicate, post an answer to the duplicated question.  If it was closed for another reason, write your own question and answer it.  If you can't make a useful question to answer, then you should leave it alone.

Comment: @hichris123: *after* a question is closed.

Comment: @bjb568: The close vote counter isn't updated on-the-fly, at least I don't see that happening, so if someone is busy writing an answer they're probably not refreshing the page to see if the close vote count is going up, especially if there weren't *any* pending votes yet at the time they started writing.

Comment: @BoltClock If there aren't any pending votes at the time they started writing, you should stop writing and add one. ;)

Comment: @HotLicks, Although in that case, you can still post your answer by manipulating the HTML and enabling the button. It will allow you to post answers up to four hours after the question is closed.

Answer (score 5):

Because at least you can edit it for that long.  Some will re-read their post and realize they meant to add in that punctuation, or just re-word a couple of things for clarity, and be on their way.

And, on the flip side, having a set time means, after which, no one needs to worry about saying something about that last comment, and then the last commenter going back and changing their comment completely, so as to make your comment look dumb and they get the upvote, and you don't, because theirs was first.

The button being there means the page hasn't been refreshed.  Sorry that SO isn't up on AJAX to take that button away from you at the 5:01 minute mark, but that's an issue for the SO programmers... Their reasons could have included any from those comments to your question (including ensuring people know they only have 5 minutes, in the future, to edit their comments).

Comment: I agree with your first two paragraphs about why there is a limit. I think what everyone is asking is why the ability to edit is misleadingly offered beyond the 5min mark and users waste their time composing an edit they then cannot post. It's a big usability defect and for a site network as big as SE/SO just not acceptable really. You sort of address this in your third paragraph, but seeing as this question was asked nearly a year ago and still nothing has been done about it, it seems the real answer is: because Stack Overflow just doesn't care.

Comment: @Mentalist - probably right.

Comment: @Mentalist Well, maybe not that they don't care, but that they care about other things more. It's not a perfect world where there are infinite developer hours that can be used to fix every single possible bug... other bugs (or features) may be taking precedence. Comments being relatively short, and the fact that it doesn't *erase* what you typed (so you can add it to another comment, if you want) mean the loss is minimal. I'd love to see this fixed, but just providing thoughts for why it's not their #1 priority...

Comment: I still find this behavior weird