# "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" re-wording

Tags: feature-request, comment-edits

[image: wait, what does image description do?]

This is a small thing, but I would interpret "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" as "You can't have the comment editing box open for more than 5 minutes" rather than "You can't edit comments posted 5 minutes ago or more". Can this be reworded to something more simple such as:

"Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes *after being posted*" (emphasis mine)

"Comments older than 5 minutes can't be edited" (thanks ryanyuyu)

Comment: "Trying to edit a comment after it's been living live for 5 minutes is harder than teaching an old dog new tricks. Your comment has earned its rights as a senior [second class] citizen and refuses your attempt to edit it."

Comment: @DavyM You may be surprised to know, [old dogs can learn new tricks](https://dogtime.com/lifestyle/dog-activities/1161-training-adult-senior-dogs-aaha), and thinking they can't is a common misconception!

Comment: "This comment is too old to edit."

Comment: The image I posted is really annoying; I keep trying to click the 'X' to make it go away...

Comment: I would prefer to see no  time limit **until** the first upvote.  That way, you can correct stupid things like mispellings, etc  that you just didn't catch.  It also would prevent editing after someone has upvoted so you don't change the nature of what they upvoted.  Deleting and re-entering doesn't help because it may change the position of your comment.  If the powers that be are worried about some sort of abuse, make it an earned capability based on some amount of rep.

Answer (score 19):

I like making the statement unambiguous.  What about:

```
"Comments may only be edited within 5 minutes of posting"
```

Answer (score -11):

How about something like this?

```
Large edits may only be done to comments within 5 minutes of posting
```

And open up all comments to (very) small edits, like correcting typos.

A concern has been raised that with this solution, one can commit several edits to a comment multiple times, to completely rephrase it. That wasn't my intention, so I'm editing in the solution here. It's relatively easy guarding against such behaviour. A small edit could consist of a maximum of `3 –> 5` changed letters. To prevent people from repeatedly editing their comment, a minimum time interval between edits can be set. I propose `6` months.

Comment: What's a small edit? What if I make hundreds of tiny edits to completely rewrite a comment?

Comment: @NickA That is kinda easy to prevent. See the edit I made.

Comment: Or compare the Levenshtein distance between the version after 5 minutes and the proposed edit. That would impose a restriction not bypassed by multiple small edits.

Comment: I don't see why this feature would be useful, it's very unlikely that somebody come across their own comment ~6 months later, found a typo and fix it. Besides, if nobody else replied to the comment, it can be deleted and reposted; if somebody replied, the comments are probably "extended discussion".