# Why am I getting "comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" at the "4 mins ago" mark?

Tags: support, comments

This is not a duplicate of [Why let me begin to edit a comment if... "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" and 5 minutes has already elapsed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266763/)   - I understand that there does have to be a hard cutoff even if your editor is still open at the 5-minute mark.

What I don't get is that often I start editing when a comment still says "4 mins ago", and after I've pressed return I get this error, yet it *still* says "4 mins ago".

Comment: I'm not sure that is a bug - that's just because the page doesn't reload. Maybe [status-works-as-designed].

Comment: OK, but is there a tag for "clearly sub-optimal undesirable misleading UI feature"?

Comment: @jez WHat would you prefer happen instead?

Comment: @Servy Perhaps clicking "edit" could trigger an update, so that the true age of the comment is then shown before you start typing.

Answer (score 3):

The time on the comment doesn't update after you load the page.  If you reload the page you'll see that the comment was posted at least 5 minutes ago.

You can't edit a comment if it has been five minutes *as of the time you submit the edit*, not as of the time the page was loaded when you started editing it.